# Fail to retrieve a secret from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

Please help, getting the next error in the Azure DevOps pipeline running on the Self-Hosted agent,
I am trying to get the keys from KV using AzureKeyVault task in pipeline settings, but facing timeout error

##[error]Get secrets failed. Error: Request timeout: /<tenant_id>/oauth2/token/.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSWeT.png)

No more logs or info :(

Comment: Hi vinilka, have you tried to use the `Azure Cli` to run `Az login` and list the keyvault by `az keyvault key list`, to see if you have enough permission to access the keyvault?

Comment: Hello Ceeno Qi-MSFT, Yes, I have performed manual steps to verify my permissions, I have managed to get a bearer token from AD App Registry and then use this token to obtain the information from the KV, but when it comes to the pipeline, it doesn't works.... it's just stuck with request timeout,

Comment: This self-hosted agent uses the Service Account, so using az login is not feasible as the account has no email associated, but I have used the REST APIs azure proving and all have been successful.